# Find most similar sentence from one list of sentences to another

Tags: scikit-learn, word2vec, word-embeddings, categorical-encoding, bag-of-words

I have two lists of short sentences (List A and List B). For each short sentence in List A, I am trying to find the most similar short sentence in List B.

Each list has a different count of elements ~10000 elements each with anywhere from 1-10 words per sentence.

What is the best way to do this in python?

I tried converting each short sentence into a one-hot vector, but due to the two lists having a different number of elements the one-hot vectors won't match length when checking cosine similarity. I figured Levenshtein distance wouldn't work in this instance and the gensim word2vec similarity function seems to work for one data set but not to find a similarity in a different list. I could be wrong with any of these assumptions though.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if the two lists correspond to two different languages? But you tried one hot vector, then do you use one vocabulary for each list? Why not combine the two vocabularies?

Comment: The brute force method computes a suitable distance between each element of A and each element of B.  There are better ways, *provided you can create an efficient lookup structure for list B.*  This would be a data structure that, when given any "probe" sentence, would return a short list (preferably unique) of nearest elements of B, and it would do this with less than O(length of B) time cost.  There's a huge number of ways to accomplish this, which you can tailor to your sense of "similar" and the specific structure of the elements of B.

Answer (score 0):

If the two lists are (ordered) translations of each other, you are doing sentence alignment.  You can refer to this paper: [Vecalign: Improved Sentence Alignment in Linear Time and Space](https://aclanthology.org/D19-1136.pdf).

If the two lists are of the same language, you can just give a try BLEU or its alternatives NIST, TER, Precision and Recall, and METEOR.

Either they are of one language or two languages, you can try the following two methods:

1. you train a predictor trained on human-labeled datasets to directly output the score;
2. you can try methods like [BERTSCORE](https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score), and you can rank the sentences in the other list for a sentence in one list by F1.

Comment: Hi, VecAlign won’t actually do what you want. It requires the two lists of sentences to be ordered, and that the sentence alignments are monotonic w.r.t that ordering. See Figure 1. (Source: I worked with Brian and Philipp around the time they were preparing this paper.) This isn’t a sentence alignment problem.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks for the correction, but it seems that the OP is no longer active on this site. I have updated my answer.